# Disk Utility on Mac crashes every time when clicking partition button

Tags: macos, macos-high-sierra

I got an issue with my Disk Utility software.
Every time I click the partition button with my ssd selected, it just crashes.I got an error:

> Application Specific Information: Performing
>   @selector(buttonPressed:) from sender NSButton 0x604000150490
>   Assertion failed: (self.minimumSize <= totalSize), function
>   -[SUPieSlice initWithPartition:startLocation:totalSpace:], file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DiskUtility/DiskUtility-1646/StorageUtility/CustomUIWidgets/SUPieSlice.m,
>   line 62.

I've looked around and tried some solutions:
Run the hard disk check and no help. I've got a warning

> Warning: Over allocation detected on main device.

Reboot with Command + S and run fsck -fy.
No help either.
I'm using a macbook pro 15 2017 with macOS 10.13.4

`diskutil list`
[diskutil output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilFFa.png)

Comment: This is not a programming question, so it will probably be closed soon. You will have more luck posting on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com), which is more set up for this sort of question.

Answer (score 2):

(To the tune of "Let it Snow")

- Oh, the Disk Utility is crashing,
- and the answer's worth rehashing:
- When the software isn't worth a lug,
- [file a bug, file a bug, file a bug.](http://bugreporter.apple.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I was suffering from the same problem. What finally helped was this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8092082

In short: there was a dataless Time Machine snapshot on my drive, and deleting it fixed the problem with Disk Utility.

Comment: Thanks, I delete all of the local snapshots and disable the auto backup. And the problem is solved

Comment: Please file a bug.  Disabling snapshots and backups should *not* be necessary to partition a disk.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was because of a second unmounted sparse disk image I had to ensure was unlocked as well. Partitioning and access worked fine from DiskUtility after that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue soon after creating a new, encrypted Time Machine volume. One partition on the disk would mount but not the TM partition. Not sure how I got in whatever state it was, but **I restarted** and the next time I plugged in the drive, I was asked for the password, and the Time Machine volume mounted.